# Unexpected results for DELETE FROM in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, delete-row

Something rare its happens in my code.

Check this:

```
if object_id('inscriptos') is not null
    drop table inscriptos;

if object_id('socios') is not null
    drop table socios;

create table socios
(
    numero int identity,
    documento char(8),
    nombre varchar(30),
    domicilio varchar(30),
    primary key (numero)
);

create table inscriptos 
(
    numerosocio int not null,
    deporte varchar(20) not null,
    matricula char(1),-- 'n' o 's'
    primary key(numerosocio, deporte),
    constraint FK_inscriptos_socio
          foreign key (numerosocio) references socios(numero)
);
GO
 
insert into socios values('23333333', 'Alberto Paredes', 'Colon 111');
insert into socios values('24444444', 'Carlos Conte', 'Sarmiento 755');
insert into socios values('25555555', 'Fabian Fuentes', 'Caseros 987');
insert into socios values('26666666', 'Hector Lopez', 'Sucre 344');

insert into inscriptos values(1, 'tenis', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(1, 'basquet', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(1, 'natacion', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(2, 'tenis', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(2, 'natacion', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(2, 'basquet', 'n');
insert into inscriptos values(2, 'futbol', 'n');
insert into inscriptos values(3, 'tenis', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(3, 'basquet', 's');
insert into inscriptos values(3, 'natacion', 'n');
insert into inscriptos values(4, 'basquet', 'n');
```

And here comes the error that I don't understand, I must delete all the rows where in the field "registration" = "n", as you can see there are only 4 records where the value "n" appears in the field registration. But in the following query deletes 8 RECORDS instead of deleting 4 RECORDS.

CODE

```
DELETE FROM inscriptos 
WHERE numerosocio IN (SELECT s.numero 
                      FROM socios AS s 
                      JOIN inscriptos AS i ON (i.numerosocio = s.numero)
                      WHERE i.matricula = 'n');
```

Do you know why this happens? I really can't understand it

THANKS!

Comment: before you run your delete command when you run `SELECT s.numero FROM socios as s  JOIN inscriptos as i ON (i.numerosocio = s.numero) WHERE i.matricula = 'n'` whats the result set?

Comment: Result: 4 rows. 
But if I run the full subquery it performs a delete 8 rows

Comment: Your inner `SELECT` returns the values `2, 2, 3, 4` - and then deletes **all** rows from `Inscriptos` that have such a value as `numerosocio` - that's **8 rows** as observed. I guess you'd need to add a `AND matricula = 'n'` condition to your `DELETE` to delete only those rows that have `n` in `matricula` - but then why do you even need that inner `SELECT ` ??

Comment: So the real question here becomes:  What are you TRYING to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `SELECT` returns this:

```
numero
------
2
2
3
4
```

And so your `DELETE` becomes

```
DELETE FROM inscriptos 
WHERE numerosocio IN (2, 3, 4)
```

If you check what rows match that condition:

```
SELECT * FROM inscriptos 
WHERE numerosocio IN (2, 3, 4)
```

you get this result - **8 rows** - and those will be deleted:

```
numerosocio   deporte   matricula
-----------------------------------
    2         basquet       n
    2         futbol        n
    2         natacion      s
    2         tenis         s
    3         basquet       s
    3         natacion      n
    3         tenis         s
    4         basquet       n
```

So what **exactly** do you want to delete??

How about this:

```
DELETE FROM inscriptos 
WHERE matricula = 'n'
```

This would delete those 4 rows with `matricula = 'n'` - why do you even need that subquery?!?!

Comment: Beat me to it! [My db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72aabaae3b2d92cc0be2cc7d17cedab6) may help others to better visualize this answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I need the subquery because in the exercise they make us perform with a subquery. Only DELETE the rows have value 'n' on "matricula".